How to send an email in same thread using Power Automate?
I am using SharePoint Online. I have created one list to store the data.
I have created two workflows for automation.
The first flow triggers when a new email arrives on Outlook online and creates a new item in the SharePoint Online list.
The second flow triggers when a list item is updated in SharePoint Online and sends an email to the user who has sent the email and item created with the first flow.
Everything works as expected but when the item is updated the second flow sends an email to the user who has sent the email and the item created using the first flow. The second flow starts a new email thread instead of sending emails in the same thread,
Can anyone help me with the same?
Thanks

You mean how to reply to an email?

Yes, I need to email in the same conversation instead of starting a new one.

You will need to use the "Reply to email" action. This needs the Message Id to reply to. You can either save the Message Id in Flow 1 and retrieve it in Flow 2, or in Flow 2 use "Get email" and search for it.

Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried the same approach, but it does not reply in the same conversation. It starts a new discussion and adds a previous email to that conversation.

That sounds like a Reply, can you elaborate on starts a new discussion? Difficult to help/answer without seeing the flow or email results.
